# Write a python program to accept a number from a user and then calculate the average of all

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, printing, sum

> Write a python program  to accept a number from a user and then calculate the average of all numbers from 1 to that given number. Then write the trace table to track the values of the variables at each iterate.

This is my attempt:

```
Range=int(input("ee: "))
Sum=0
Average=0
for i in range(1,Range):
    sum=sum+i
Average=sum/i
print(Average,"   ",i)
```

I get an error on line 4.

Comment: `Sum` != `sum`. And don't use built-in as variables.

Comment: In line 5 the word sum, S has to be capital

Answer (score 1):

`sum` is a keyword, you meant to use `Sum` (The variable you declared) in line 5 and 6.

```
Range=int(input("ee: "))
Sum=0
Average=0
for i in range(1,Range + 1):
    Sum=Sum+i
Average=Sum/i
print(Average,"   ",i)
```

Also notice I have made it Range + 1. This is because the limit is not inclusive in the `range()` function.

You could also make the code a little compact like this:

```
count = int(input("ee: "))

total = sum(range(1, count + 1))
average = total / count

print(average)
```

Or just

```
count = int(input("ee: "))

average = sum(range(1, count + 1)) / count

print(average)
```